# Подскажите как отключить bitbucket pipelines test result

Tags: bitbucket, непрерывная-интеграция

Сегодня днем обнаружила, что bitbucket pipelines выпустили сегодня новую feature - это test result после каждого рана. Мне нужно отключить этот test result, потому что он блокирует нашу отправку test result, может кто знает как это можно решить?

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема разрешилась сама собой - bitbucket сам отключил эту feature